# Recommended way to transform data when using Django Rest Framework Serializers

Tags: django-rest-framework

When using Django Rest Framework Serializers, what is the recommended way to transform data? eg:

input:

```
{
   "companyName" : "Acme , inc.",
   "id": 2,
   "parent": {
      "id": 1
   }
}
```

desired output:

```
{
   "name" : "Acme , inc.",
   "id": 2,
   "parentId": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Serializer Method Field:

```
class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    parentId = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = 
        fields = ('name', 'parentId')

    def get_name(self, obj):
        #write logic

    def get_parentId(self, obj):
        #write logic
```

Comment: That looks reasonable :-)
Can you provide a pointer to this technique in the "official" doc? (i looked, but wasn't obvious)
What exactly needs to be placed under these method fields and what is their input and output signature?
Is it just mapping logic, or does it need to include validation as well?
ie, when you call Serializer.is_valid(), will that be handled automagically, or does it need to be handled here?

Comment: You will need to write your own validation, either with is_valid() or validators (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/). 

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: Hmmh, that is sub-optimal... I just need to remap fields and would like to rely on the serializers' built-in validation... seems like transforming outside of the serializer would be a lot simpler...

Comment: One more question: I actually want to do this on deserialization, does SerializerMethodField apply in that case, if so, how?

Comment: What If I need to do similar when creating object, I get one data from request, but need to transform it to another data for saving to model.

Comment: Neat answer...!